# The request to list features available on the specified server failed: Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012

I am having a problem with the server manager in my Windows Server 2012 R2 Machine .

Everytime I try to add a Role I get this error message

> The request to list features available on the specified server failed

[image]

Why ?

Comment: Can you try to list the available features with this command and see if it works :
Get-WindowsFeature

Comment: When I do  **Get-WindowsFeature –** I get this message error    [link](https://imgur.com/a/d7PNSVE)

Answer (score 5):

Try to get a list using a PowerShell. Most probably, the server stuck on the pending reboot request. The first option will be rebooting, installing Windows updates and then rebooting once again. The second option is to delete pending.xml in C:\Windows\WinSxS and reboot the host.

Comment: it s not stuck on an update , I rebooted it a thousand times

Answer (score 0):

I had this on Windows Server 2016, when C:\Windows\system32\downlevel folder had other files than DLLs in it. There was a .txt file in there. I deleted that .txt, and Server roles started to open, and Get-WindowsFeature started to work.

Besides, I had an additional symptom. Running:
dism /online /cleanup-image /checkhealth
was showing DISM Error 193.

Thanks to @Cybot resolving this at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/dism-error-193/f5c78f44-0bd0-47cf-812d-f1fe7d311199